# How to use combobox (Tkinter)?

Tags: python, function, tkinter, combobox, ttk

I'm currently working on a retail management system project using Tkinter as the GUI framework. The system's interface is designed to use an image as the background, and buttons are placed over the image in specified areas.

I've managed to display the buttons and entry boxes, but I'm having trouble getting the combobox to display on the interface.

This is the output of my main program:[Click link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ln7Sx.png)

My code:

```
#BBCVZJS0
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox
import tkinter as tk
import sqlite3
import tkinter.messagebox as messagebox

def main_window():
        # create a new window
    invoice = Toplevel()
    # load the image file
    billimage1 = PhotoImage(file="C:/Users/hasee/OneDrive/Documents/CODE/billimage.PNG")
    # create a label widget and set it as the background of the window
    label2 = Label(invoice, image = billimage1)
    label2.pack()
    
    def search_bill():
            # Connect to the database
        conn = sqlite3.connect('store.db')
        c = conn.cursor()

        # Get the value of the bill entry box
        bill_no = bill_entry.get()

        # Execute a query to fetch the bill number from the database
        c.execute("SELECT bill_no FROM bill WHERE bill_no = ?", (bill_no,))
        result = c.fetchone()

        # Check if the result is not None
        if result is not None:
        # Execute a query to fetch the product information from the inventory table
            c.execute("SELECT product_name, price, quantity FROM raw_inventory WHERE product_name = 'Big G Cereals Cinnamon Toast Crunch' AND price = 12 AND quantity = 10")
            product_info = c.fetchone()

            # Execute a query to fetch the customer information from the bill table
            c.execute("SELECT customer_name, customer_no FROM bill WHERE customer_name = 'Adam Fawn' AND customer_no = '02086132851'")
            customer_info = c.fetchone()

            # Close the database connection
            conn.close()

            # Check if both the product and customer information are not None
            if product_info is not None and customer_info is not None:
                # Create labels to display the product and customer information
                product_label = tk.Label(invoice, text=f"{product_info[0]}{' ' * 45}{product_info[1]}{' ' * 83}£{product_info[2]}", font=("Arial", 13), bg="white")
                customer_label = tk.Label(invoice, text=f"{customer_info[0]}{' ' * 109}Phone Number:  {customer_info[1]}", font=("Arial", 13), bg="white")
                bill_label = tk.Label(invoice, text=f"{bill_no}", font=("Arial", 13), bg="white")
                total_label = tk.Label(invoice, text=f"Total: £{product_info[2]}", font=("Arial", 15), bg="white", fg = "red")

                # Place the labels on the GUI
                product_label.place(relx=0.44, rely=0.6)
                customer_label.place(relx=0.52, rely=0.458)
                bill_label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.483)
                total_label.place(relx = 0.44, rely =0.65)

        else:
            # Close the database connection
            conn.close()

            # Show a message box to indicate that the search was unsuccessful
            messagebox.showwarning("Search Result", "Bill number does not exist in the database")
            
    def generate_bill():
        conn = sqlite3.connect('store.db')
        c = conn.cursor()

        # Get the values from the entry boxes
        cust_name2 = cust_name.get()
        contact_num2 = contact_num.get()

        c.execute("SELECT customer_name FROM bill WHERE customer_name = 'Adam Fawn'")
        customer_check = c.fetchone()

        c.execute("SELECT customer_no FROM bill WHERE customer_no = '02086132851'")
        phone_check = c.fetchone()

        # Check if the customer name and contact number are not empty
        if cust_name2 and contact_num2:
            # Check if the customer name and contact number match the values in the database
            if cust_name2 == customer_check[0] and contact_num2 == phone_check[0]:
                # Get the bill from the search_bill function
                
                conn = sqlite3.connect('store.db')
                c = conn.cursor()
                
                bill_no = bill_entry.get()

                # Execute a query to fetch the bill number from the database
                c.execute("SELECT bill_no FROM bill WHERE bill_no = ?", (bill_no,))
                result = c.fetchone()
                
                c.execute("SELECT product_name, price, quantity FROM raw_inventory WHERE product_name = 'Big G Cereals Cinnamon Toast Crunch' AND price = 12 AND quantity = 10")
                product_info = c.fetchone()

                # Execute a query to fetch the customer information from the bill table
                c.execute("SELECT customer_name, customer_no FROM bill WHERE customer_name = 'Adam Fawn' AND customer_no = '02086132851'")
                customer_info = c.fetchone()

                # Close the database connection
                conn.close()
                
                product_label = tk.Label(invoice, text=f"{product_info[0]}{' ' * 45}{product_info[1]}{' ' * 83}£{product_info[2]}", font=("Arial", 13), bg="white")
                customer_label = tk.Label(invoice, text=f"{customer_info[0]}{' ' * 109}Phone Number:  {customer_info[1]}", font=("Arial", 13), bg="white")
                bill_label = tk.Label(invoice, text=f"{bill_no}", font=("Arial", 13), bg="white")
                total_label = tk.Label(invoice, text=f"Total: £{product_info[2]}", font=("Arial", 15), bg="white", fg = "red")

                # Place the labels on the GUI
                product_label.place(relx=0.44, rely=0.6)
                customer_label.place(relx=0.52, rely=0.458)
                bill_label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.483)
                total_label.place(relx = 0.44, rely =0.65)

                # Display a message to the user that the bill is generated
                messagebox.showinfo("Bill Generated", "The bill has been generated.")
            else:
                # Display an error message to the user that the customer name and contact number do not match
                messagebox.showerror("Error", "The customer name or contact number is incorrect.")
        else:
            # Display an error message to the user that they need to enter values
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please enter a customer name and contact number.")
            
    def clear_bill():
        invoice.destroy()
        main_window()
        
    def dropdown():
        # create a Combobox widget with items from the 'items' list
        combo = Combobox(invoice, values=items)
        # set the default value to the first item in the list
        combo.current(0)
        items = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3']
        combo.pack()

        # set up the variables
        
        

    
    
    logout_img = tk.PhotoImage(file="C:/Users/hasee/OneDrive/Documents/CODE/logout.PNG")
    logout_button = tk.Button(invoice, image=logout_img, command="", borderwidth=0, bg='white')
    logout_button.place(relx=0.025, rely=0.099)
    
    search_img = tk.PhotoImage(file="C:/Users/hasee/OneDrive/Documents/CODE/search.PNG")
    search_button = tk.Button(invoice, image=search_img, command = search_bill, borderwidth=0, bg='white')
    search_button.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.22)
    
    cart_img = tk.PhotoImage(file="C:/Users/hasee/OneDrive/Documents/CODE/cart.PNG")
    cart_button = tk.Button(invoice, image=cart_img, command="", borderwidth=0, bg='white')
    cart_button.place(relx=0.085, rely=0.725)
    
    remove_img = tk.PhotoImage(file="C:/Users/hasee/OneDrive/Documents/CODE/remove.PNG")
    remove_button = tk.Button(invoice, image=remove_img, command="", borderwidth=0, bg='white')
    remove_button.place(relx=0.176, rely=0.722)
    
    clear_img = tk.PhotoImage(file="C:/Users/hasee/OneDrive/Documents/CODE/clear.PNG")
    clear_button = tk.Button(invoice, image=clear_img, command=clear_bill, borderwidth=0, bg='white')
    clear_button.place(relx=0.265, rely=0.72)
    
    clear_img2 = tk.PhotoImage(file="C:/Users/hasee/OneDrive/Documents/CODE/clear.PNG")
    clear_button2 = tk.Button(invoice, image=clear_img2, command="", borderwidth=0, bg='white')
    clear_button2.place(relx=0.22, rely=0.871)
    
    total_img = tk.PhotoImage(file="C:/Users/hasee/OneDrive/Documents/CODE/total.PNG")
    total_button = tk.Button(invoice, image=total_img, command="", borderwidth=0, bg='white')
    total_button.place(relx=0.04, rely=0.878)
    
    generate_img = tk.PhotoImage(file="C:/Users/hasee/OneDrive/Documents/CODE/generate.PNG")
    generate_button = tk.Button(invoice, image=generate_img, command=generate_bill, borderwidth=0, bg='white')
    generate_button.place(relx=0.13, rely=0.875)
    
    exit_img = tk.PhotoImage(file="C:/Users/hasee/OneDrive/Documents/CODE/exit.PNG")
    exit_button = tk.Button(invoice, image=exit_img, command="", borderwidth=0, bg='white')
    exit_button.place(relx=0.31, rely=0.8715)
    
    bill_entry = tk.Entry(invoice, width=20, font=("Arial", 20), bd = 0) # create an textbox for the phone number
    bill_entry.place(relx=0.105, rely=0.235)
    
    cust_name = tk.Entry(invoice, width=20, font=("Arial", 20), bd = 0) # create an textbox for the phone number
    cust_name.place(relx=0.515, rely=0.235)
    
    contact_num = tk.Entry(invoice, width=20, font=("Arial", 20), bd = 0) # create an textbox for the phone number
    contact_num.place(relx=0.795, rely=0.235)
    
    
    invoice.mainloop()
                        
main_window()
```

The code for writing up the combobox:

```
def dropdown():
        # create a Combobox widget with items from the 'items' list
        combo = Combobox(invoice, values=items)
        # set the default value to the first item in the list
        combo.current(0)
        items = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3']
        combo.pack()
```

At the moment, my dropdown() function is quite simple in terms of the items on the list that I'm working with. However, I'm facing an issue where the combobox is not being displayed on the GUI. I've tried using the place() method to see if it can fix the problem, but unfortunately it didn't.

I've also attempted to run the combobox function on its own, and it was successfully displayed. However, when I integrate it with the rest of my code, the combobox is not showing up. I'm starting to suspect that there might be an issue with the image that I'm using as my background. Do you have any ideas or suggestions on how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: `from tkinter import ttk` `combo = ttk.Combobox(invoice,....`

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I cannot test your program because you do not provide the PNG files. Also, your code your be more portable if you use relative paths for your files. There is no C:/users/hasee on my machine.

Comment: `dropdowm()` has never been called in your code. Also `items` is used before it is defined, so exception should be raised when this function is executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a StringVar or IntVar or even a FloatVar to get the values from the Combobox back uesing  callback functio. The Varaible should be traced with "varaible".trace('w', "callback_function_name"

Try this:

```
combo_output_var = StringVar()  # output variabel for the combobox -> callback function with trace should be used!
combobox_list = Combobox(invoice, textvariable= combo_output_var)  # Create the combobox
combobox_list['values'] = items  # Give the Combobox all the selectable values
combobox_list['state']  = 'readonly  # The state from the combobox could be set... ('readonly' is mostly used) 
combobox_list.current(index_items)  # Set the default visible value 
combobox.pack()  # Pack the combobox
```